# Encrypt and Decrypt Elgamal

Tags: c#

I'm writing a program to encode and decode Elgamal in c# windows form. The program requirements are to encode and decode all font formats: font style, foreground, font family. I converted the string to a byte array using `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text)` and then converted the byte to base64 format and apply the extended euclidean algorithm find the inverse and the square and multiply algorithm to encode and decode back. But my plaintext can only decode default text but not typeface formats.
Here is my encryt code:

```
        private string Encode()
        {
            //Tinh y1
            y1 = binhphuong(alpha, k, p);
            banro = txtTest.Text;
            string loi = "";
            string kqBanMa = "";
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(banro))
            {
                loi = "\n Bạn phải nhập bản rõ";
            }
            if (txtA.Text == "" || txtAlpha.Text == "" || txtAlpha.Text == "" || txtBeta.Text == "" || txtP.Text == "" || txtPDoc.Text == "")
            {
                loi += "\n Bạn chưa tạo khóa";
            }
            if (loi != "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Có lỗi xảy ra : " + loi, "Thông báo", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!Regex.IsMatch(banro, @"^\d+$"))
                {
                    // Chuyển chuỗi qua dạng mảng byte
                    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(banro);

                    //Chuyển từ byte sang dạng Base 64
                    string dang64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

                    //chuyển các kí tự cần mã hóa về dạng số và lưu vào 1 list
                    List<int> c1 = new List<int>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < dang64.Length; i++)
                        c1.Add((int)dang64[i]);

                    //mã hóa từng kí tự dưới dạng số
                    List<int> c2 = new List<int>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < c1.Count; i++)
                    {
                        int chuyendoi = ((c1[i] % p) * binhphuong(beta, k, p)) % p;
                        c2.Add(chuyendoi);
                    }

                    //chuyển các kí tự mã hóa dưới dạng số về dạng chữ trong ASCII và nối lại
                    string c = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < c2.Count; i++)
                        c += (char)c2[i];

                    /*
                     Do mã hóa dựa trên bảng mã ASCII nên các kí tự bị mã hóa thành các kí tự đặc biệt khá khó chịu nên
                     chuyển nó qua dạng base 64 để dễ nhìn hơn.
                     */

                    //Chuyển chuỗi sau mã hóa thành mảng byte
                    byte[] byt = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(c);

                    //Chuyển từ mảng byte sang dạng Base 64
                    kqBanMa = Convert.ToBase64String(byt);
                    //return kqBanMa1;
                }
                else
                {
                    int dangso = int.Parse(banro.ToString());

                    //Tinh y2
                    y2 = ((dangso % p) * (binhphuong(beta, k, p))) % p;

                    kqBanMa = $"Bản mã C = (C1, C2) = ({y1}, {y2})";
                }
            }
            return kqBanMa;
        }
```

And here is my decrypt code:

```
private string Decode()
        {
            int pt1 = binhphuong(y1, a, p);
            int pt2 = songhichdao(pt1, p);
            banma = txtReCipher.Text;
            string gm = "";
            try
            {
                if (banma.Length == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Có lỗi xảy ra : Chưa có bản mã để giải mã", "Thông báo", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!Regex.IsMatch(banro, @"^\d+$"))
                    {
                        //chuyển chuỗi dạng base 64 qua mảng byte
                        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(banma);

                        //chuyển từ mảng byte về chuỗi sau khi mã hóa
                        string strMaHoa = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes);

                        //chuyển các kí tự qua dạng số
                        List<int> temp1 = new List<int>();
                        foreach (int item in strMaHoa)
                            temp1.Add((int)item);

                        //giải mã từng kí tự
                        List<int> temp2 = new List<int>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < temp1.Count; i++)
                        {
                            int element = ((temp1[i] % p) * pt2) % p;

                            temp2.Add(element);// giải mã
                        }

                        //chuyển các đã mã hóa qua dạng chữ và nối lại thành chuỗi
                        string temp = "";
                        for (int i = 0; i < temp2.Count; i++)
                            temp += (char)temp2[i];

                        // chuyển chuỗi giải mã sang dạng bytes
                        byte[] bytesLast = Convert.FromBase64String(temp);


                        //chuyển từ mảng byte sang chuỗi đã giải mã
                        gm = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytesLast);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int ptso = ((y2 % p) * pt2) % p;
                        gm = ptso.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Có lỗi xảy ra", "Thông báo", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            return gm;

        }
```

I hope everyone can help me complete this program as soon as possible. Thanks so much.

Comment: Why are you converting the buffer to a BASE64 string instead of working with the byte values?

Comment: You should split your code in distinct steps: 1. Convert your data into bytes and back again, 2. Encrypt/Decrypt your bytes. This should let you test each part independently to see if the problem is in the encryption/decryption or in the serialization/deserialization step.